# How do I position two divs horizontally along side another div using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What exactly do I need to do to accomplish something like this:

[image]

Till now I've done the following:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            thumbnail
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <div class="col-md-8">
              title
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
              bottom row
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us your efforts first and then we can help

Comment: Post your html and css.so it would be easier to modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.

One can be using grid system (like you tried):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="one col-xs-4">ONE<br/>ONE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="two col-xs-12">TWO</div>
                <div class="three col-xs-12">THREE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj1dbh1v/).

Since you wrote "thumbnail" I think you may be looking for Bootstrap media objects, check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media).

Let me know if this was useful!

Answer (score 0):

your html should be like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/50X50" class="img-thumbnail"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>title</p>
                <p> bottom row</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i give you just bootstrap format .